# How to Count number of counts in groupby clause count values

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

How to count result of count by group by clause result

```
select count(*) 
from
( 
  select first_name,count(first_name) 
  from actor
  group by first_name
  having count(first_name) in (2,4) 
);
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: How is this not the result you want?  This will give you the number of distinct first_names

Comment: you're missing an alias for your derived table i.e. the last line should be `) t1;`

Comment: Your query, as written, will give you the number of records in `actor` where there are either 2 or 4 instances of the same first_name. Is this not what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the alias of the derived table:

```
select count(*) 
from
( 
  select first_name,count(first_name) 
  from actor
  group by first_name
  having count(first_name) in (2,4) 
) as t ;               
   --^
   --|------------------------ alias "t"
```

The query could also be simplified a bit to:

```
select count(*) 
from
(                         -- the columns can be skipped, 
  select 1                -- as they are not needed in the upper level
  from actor 
  group by first_name
  having count(*) in (2,4) 
) as t ;
```

or obfuscated to:

```
select distinct 
    count(case when count(*) in (2,4) then 1 end) over () 
from actor
group by first_name ;
```